# Newtonsoft, deserialize and convert json string element to property in an object property

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

How would map an element from a json object into a property of a object that is a property on my main class.

So for example:

```
public ParentClass{
    public SubClass theClass {get; set;}
}

public SubClass{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentClass>(jsonString);
```

And the json string is something like:

```
{
   "id":123,
   "name": "Bob"
}
```

So id would end up in the value of SubClass.Id.

Comment: If the json represent the SubClass then why do you try to deserialze to ParentClass?. Just deserialze to the correct object then insert the SubClass instance into an instance of your ParentClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deserialize it to `SubClass` like this

```
var theClass  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubClass>(jsonString);
var mainClass = new ParentClass{theClass  =theClass  }
```